# Connection string query MS Visual Studio 2010-MS Access 2007 database

Tags: ms-access, database-connection, connection-string

I'm just new to C# and I wonder how to construct a connection string from Visual Studio 2010 to MS Access 2007 database

Database name: dbsPolar

could you please guide me through? Though there are can be research in the net be I wanted to be clear with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="location"\dbsPolar.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;
```

Location is the folder location the dbsPolar db is located in.

For more information you can view this question.
[StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346261/ado-dot-netconnection-string-with-access-2007)

Also a good place to find connection strings examples take a look at [ConnectString.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/).  For Access 2007 connection strings look here [Access 2007 connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007/)